# Adding a Computed column with After clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a computed column after a specified column.

But the SQL gives syntax error for the query below. Please help me with the correct syntax/way to do this.

```
ALTER TABLE service_ServiceClass 
  ADD LichenClassName AS ([dbo].[UfnGetServiceClassName]([Id])) AFTER Description
```

Comment: This is not possible in SQL Server. [After](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) clause is not available. I think you can do it in MySQL though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an error because "AFTER" is MySQL syntax.
There is no direct way to alter column order in SQL Server currently.

In MS SQL Server Management Studio, you'd have to use the SSMS Table Designer (rightclick yourTable->Design) to arrange your columns, which can then generate a script which drops and recreates the table.

Comment: Why would you have to drop and recreate the table?

Comment: @DanBracuk - because there's no way in SQL Server to re-arrange the columns in a table. So if you insist on "changing" the column order, the only way to achieve that is to re-create the table with the changed layout.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `after` clause in sql server's [`alter table`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) statement.
The order of the columns in the table (as well is the order of the rows, btw) is completely insignificant from a user's point of view.
It's significant from the server point of view, as it may effect performance when using clustered indexes.

The only time the order of the columns matters is when you are using `select * ...`, but you shouldn't use that anyway. Always specify the column names directly.

Comment: The order of the rows and columns are not insignificant.  Clustered indexes control the ordering of the rows, and are sometimes important for performance.  If column types have alignment preferences, then the ordering of columns is also significant -- you can't control it very well in SQL Server, but it can be significant.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, I've edited my answer. I hope it's more accurate now.